# Storing vector of chars in Redis - containing NUL

Tags: c++, redis, hiredis

I want to store a JPEG image in redis as a single key-value pair.
From OpenCV, I get a `std::vector<unsigned char> jpeg` from `imencode()`

Now I convert this vector to `std::string` and `SET` it with Hiredis.
The problem is that the `jpeg` vector contains `NUL` characters (`ANSII == 0`) and the Hiredis `SET` function receives `value.c_str()`. `.c_str()` truncates the string after the first occurrence of `NUL`, and therefore only this substring is stored in the DB.

My question is: How can I `SET` and `GET` a `std::vector<unsigned char>` (containing `NUL`) with Hiredis? (Minimizing runtime is critical.)

Here is my code:

```
// Create vector of uchars, = From CV [Disregard inefficiency here]

std::vector<unsigned char> jpeg;
jpeg.push_back( 'a' );
jpeg.push_back( 'b' );
jpeg.push_back( (unsigned char) 0 );
jpeg.push_back( 'c' );
jpeg.push_back( 'd' );

// Convert to string

std::string word = "";
for (int i=0; i<jpeg.size(); ++i)
{
    word.push_back(jpeg[i]);
}

std::cout << "word = " << word << std::endl;
std::cout << "word.c_str() = " << word.c_str() << std::endl;

// connect redis

std::string hostname = "127.0.0.1";
int port = 6379;
timeval timeout = { 1, 500000 }; // 1.5 seconds
redisContext* context = redisConnectWithTimeout(hostname.c_str(), port, timeout);

// set redis

std::string key = "jpeg";
redisReply* reply = (redisReply *)redisCommand(context, "SET %s %s", key.c_str(), word.c_str() );
freeReplyObject( (void*) reply);

// get redis

reply = (redisReply *)redisCommand(context, "GET %s", key.c_str() );
std::string value = reply->str;
freeReplyObject((void*) reply);
std::cout << "returned value = " << value << std::endl;

// Convert back to vector of uchars (this should be the same as the original jpeg)  [Disregard inefficiency here]

std::vector<unsigned char> jpeg_returned;
for (int i=0; i<value.size(); ++i)
{
    jpeg_returned.push_back(value[i]);
    // std::cout << "value[i] = " << value[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: While `std::string` can store arbitrary data, you really can not use string functions when dealing with binary data (which is what a JPEG image is). Doesn't Redis has some kind of binary blob type?

Comment: Actually HiRedis lib has binary support and you don't need to convert std::vector to std::string before storing it. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26799074/can-we-set-c-int-array-as-a-keys-value-in-redis-by-hiredis

Comment: *.c_str() truncates the string after the first occurrence of NUL* -- This is not true.  It is not `c_str()` that is truncating the string, it's the functions that you're giving `c_str()` to that stop on the first NULL.  [See the documentation on c_str()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str).  For example, your usage of `cout` will not work like that, as you would need to use `cout.write(word.c_str(), word.size())` to properly output the entire string.

Comment: Yes, jpeg is binary but opencv returns a vec<char>, which is just begging to be stored in redis as a string. The only problem really is the NUL char. I saw link before, the author does not recommend this method. It would also be nice if I could read this jpg from another python app.

Comment: Sir, can you share your code about storing Opencv image into Redis using C++ and reading it using Python? It will help me a lot, thanks!

Comment: Sir, can you share your code about storing Opencv image into Redis using C++ and reading it using Python? It will help me a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before showing a code I want to warn one more time that storing binary data without proper serialization can be problematic. At least make sure all your servers are the same endianness and has the same sizeof(int).

```
std::vector<char> v{'A', 'B', '\0', 'C', 'D'};

std::string key = "jpeg";
redisReply* reply = static_cast<redisReply *>( redisCommand(context, "SET %s %b", key.c_str(), v.data(), v.size() ) );
freeReplyObject( reply );
```

And reading from python.

```
>>> import redis
>>> r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
>>> r.get("jpeg")
'AB\x00CD'
```

Comment: Thank you! I implemented the get functionality, based on your other post:
    `redisReply* reply = (redisReply *) redisCommand(context, "GET %s", a_key.c_str() );
    unsigned char *val = (unsigned char *) malloc( reply->len );
    memcpy( val, reply->str, reply->len);
    std::vector<unsigned char> jped_returned(val, val + reply->len);
    free( val );
    freeReplyObject(reply);`
Is this the most efficient way?

Comment: @user2926577 I guess yes. why do you allocate c-style array then copy into std::vector. You should be able to create std::vector<unsigned char> jped_returned directly from reply->str and reply->len.

Comment: I was following your comment `// Here, it is safer to make a copy to be sure memory is properly aligned`, I'm actually not sure why this is advised here. I  created a pointer to the array, there shouldn't be any deep copies happening here. Could you post the c++ code for binary GET as you would have optimized it? Thank you

Comment: @user2926577 you can do something like this: `reply = static_cast<redisReply *>(redisCommand(context, "GET %s", key.c_str() ) );` `std::vector<unsigned char> read_vector( reply->str, reply->str+reply->len );`